# Conversational facebook messenger bot

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

Hi I am making a new bot for a product where I need to ask customer login id and password.

So for my case, user would initiate a conversation by typing `hi` then bot will reply `Hey! How can I help you`, here if customer enter `I want to transfer money` then bot will respond `Please enter a login ID`, first here customer will enter login id and bot will respond `Enter your password` then it goes like this.

I have done like below in node js which seems not a correct way to me.

```
app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {

    let messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging
    for (let i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
        let event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i]
        let sender = event.sender.id
        if (event.message && event.message.text) {
            let text = event.message.text.toLowerCase();
            var greets = ['hi', 'hey', 'hello', 'good morning', 'good evening']
            if(greets.indexOf(text) > -1) {
                sendTextMessage(sender, 'Hey! How can I help you ?')
            }
            else if((text.indexOf('money transfer') > -1) || (text.indexOf('transfer money') > -1)) {
                sendTextMessage(sender, 'OK. Please enter your login details.')
                lastMessage = 'Please enter your login ID.'
            } else if(text.indexOf('restart') > -1) {
                lastMessage = ''
                sendTextMessage(sender, 'Thanks, Give a seconds to me :)')
            }
            else {
                sendTextMessage(sender, 'Huh! Uhhh broke me :(')
            }
        } else if (event.postback) {
            var payload = event.postback.payload;
            if(payload) {
                // When a postback is called, we'll send a message back to the sender to 
                // let them know it was successful.
                // do nothing
                switch (payload) {
                    case 'USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD':
                        sendTextMessage(sender, 'Welcome to XXX, What are you looking for today ?')
                        break;
                }
            }
            console.log("Postback received: " + JSON.stringify(event.postback));
        }
    }
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

What is the best way to achieve my case, how flow will be maintained if user enter a login id then bot would ask for password.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is send a **external link** to customer, or send a structured message with a url button that customer could click and link to outside. So your external link should bring user's `sender_id`. Once your customer has logged in at external link, your callback function could then tell bot to send a **login success!** message, then you can continue the conversation.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without redirecting outside the messenger bot?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think asking for user and password in plain text message it isn't secure way to be implemented, also bad user experience.

Instead, provide **an external link for user login process**

or take a look at

**Account Linking**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/account-linking

> Account Linking starts a authentication process allowing a Messenger
>   user to log-in using your own authentication flow, and link his or her
>   business account.

Comment: I don't think Account Linking works? any samples that work in real life?  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2274